# Recursive HTML table tree using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I developed clicking on the parent node to display its child row. I just need to enable to click on the child data should open its sub child rows as recursive one or table tree. Could anyone add your logic which will help me to understand and help the same to others?

```js
document.getElementById("products").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "A") {
        e.preventDefault();
        var row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        while ((row = nextTr(row)) && !/\bparent\b/ .test(row.className))
            toggle_it(row);
    }
});

function nextTr(row) {
    while ((row = row.nextSibling) && row.nodeType != 1);
    return row;
}

function toggle_it(item){ 
     if (/\bopen\b/.test(item.className))
         item.className = item.className.replace(/\bopen\b/," ");
     else
         item.className += " open";
 }
```

```css
tbody tr {
    display : none;
}
tr.parent {
    display : table-row;
}
tr.open {
    display : table-row;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <table class="table" id="products">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Updated on</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="parent">
    <td><a href="#">+</a>Oranges</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>On Store</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>121</td>
        <td>120</td>
        <td>City 1</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>212</td>
        <td>140</td>
        <td>City 2</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>212</td>
        <td>140</td>
        <td>City 2</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td><a href="#">+</a>Apples</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>On Store</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>120</td>
        <td>120</td>
        <td>City 1</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>120</td>
        <td>140</td>
        <td>City 2</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

I've changed almost everything and simplified the code:

- The toggle buttons are added automatically,
- <kbd>+</kbd> changes to <kbd>-</kbd> when the parent is opened,
- The table, the classes for opened and visible elements, and the buttons are passed as parameters,
- It could be used on multiple table,
- …

I've created a repository with that code on GitHub:
https://github.com/TakitIsy/table-to-tree

```js
/* ---- < MAIN FUNCTION > ---- */
function tableToTree(table_Selector, tr_OpenedClass, tr_VisibleClass, tr_ToggleButton) {

  // Table elements variables
  var table = document.querySelector(table_Selector);
  var trs = document.querySelectorAll(table_Selector + " tr");

  // Add the buttons above the table
  var buttons = document.createElement('div');
  buttons.innerHTML = '<button>[‒] All</button><button>[+] All</button>';
  table.insertBefore(buttons, table.childNodes[0]);
  buttons = buttons.querySelectorAll('button');
  // Add the actions of these buttons
  buttons[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    trs.forEach(function(elm) {
      elm.classList.remove(tr_OpenedClass);
      elm.classList.remove(tr_VisibleClass);
    });
  });
  buttons[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
    trs.forEach(function(elm) {
      if (elm.innerHTML.includes(tr_ToggleButton))
        elm.classList.add(tr_OpenedClass);
      elm.classList.add(tr_VisibleClass);
    });
  });

  // Next tr function
  function nextTr(row) {
    while ((row = row.nextSibling) && row.nodeType != 1);
    return row;
  }

  // On creation, automatically add toggle buttons if the tr has childs elements
  trs.forEach(function(tr, index) {
    if (index < trs.length - 1) {
      if (+tr.getAttribute("level") < +trs[index + 1].getAttribute("level")) {
        var elm1 = tr.firstElementChild;
        elm1.innerHTML = tr_ToggleButton + elm1.innerHTML;
      }
    }
  });

  // Use the buttons added by the function above
  table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
    // Event management
    if (!e) return;
    if (e.target.outerHTML !== tr_ToggleButton) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Get the parent tr and its level
    var row = e.target.closest("tr");
    row.classList.toggle(tr_OpenedClass);
    var lvl = +(row.getAttribute("level"));

    // Loop to make childs visible/hidden
    while ((row = nextTr(row)) && ((+(row.getAttribute("level")) == (lvl + 1)) || row.className.includes(tr_VisibleClass))) {
      row.classList.remove(tr_OpenedClass);
      row.classList.toggle(tr_VisibleClass);
    }
  });

}
/* ---- </ MAIN FUNCTION > ---- */

// Call the above main function to make the table tree-like
tableToTree('#myTable', 'opened', 'visible', '<span class="toggle"></span>');
```

```css
tbody tr {
  display: none;
}

tr[level="0"],
tr.visible {
  display: table-row;
}

td {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 32px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr[level="1"] td {
  background: #ddd;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

tr[level="2"] td {
  background: #eee;
  padding-left: 48px;
}

tr .toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle::after {
  content: "[+]";
}

.opened .toggle::after {
  content: "[‒]";
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr level="0">
      <td>Parent 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr level="1">
      <td>Match 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr level="1">
      <td>Match 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr level="0">
      <td>Parent 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr level="1">
      <td>Mismatch 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr level="1">
      <td>Mismatch 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr level="2">
      <td>Mismatch 2.1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Old answer**

I played a little with your code…
Trying to use as many as possible of existing functions/methods to make the code cleaner and easier to read and understand.

… and ended-up with that snippet:
(See comments in my code for more details)

```js
document.getElementById("products").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // I think using the not equal is nicer here, just my opinion… Less indenting.
  if (!e) return;                       // Exit if null
  if (e.target.tagName !== "A") return; // Exit if not A element

  e.preventDefault();
  var row = e.target.closest("tr"); // Better than parent parent!
  var cls = row.classList[0];       // Get the first class name (the only one in our html)
  var lvl = +(cls.slice(-1)) + 1;   // Unary operator +1 on the last character
  cls = cls.slice(0, -1) + lvl;     // Replace the last char with lvl to get the class to be toggled

  // Check if the row is of the class to be displayed OR if the row is already opened
  // (so that clicking close on parent also closes sub-childs)
  while ((row = nextTr(row)) && (row.className.includes(cls) || row.className.includes("open")))
    row.classList.toggle("open"); // Better than the function you created, it already exists!
});

function nextTr(row) {
  while ((row = row.nextSibling) && row.nodeType != 1);
  return row;
}

// Select all the tr childs elements (all levels except 0
var allChilds = document.querySelectorAll("tr[class^=level]:not(.level0)");
// Added the below for buttons after comments
document.getElementById("openAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  allChilds.forEach(function(elm){
    elm.classList.add("open");
  });
});
document.getElementById("closeAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  allChilds.forEach(function(elm){
    elm.classList.remove("open");
  });
});
```

```css
tbody tr {
  display: none;
}


/* Simplified */

tr.level0,
tr.open {
  display: table-row;
}


/* Added colors for better visibility */

tr.level0 {
  background: #ccc;
}

tr.level1 {
  background: #ddd;
}

tr.level2 {
  background: #eee;
}


/* Added some more styling after comment */

tr td {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

tr td:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

tr td a {
  color: inherit;
  /* No special color */
  text-decoration: inherit;
  /* No underline */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.25em;
}

tr.level1 td:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

tr.level2 td:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<button id="openAll">+ All</button>
<button id="closeAll">- All</button>
<table class="table" id="products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th>Updated on</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="level0">
      <td><a href="#">+</a>Oranges</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>On Store</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td>121</td>
      <td>120</td>
      <td>City 1</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td><a href="#">+</a>212</td>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>City 2</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
      <td>212</td>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>City 2</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
      <td>212</td>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>City 2</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level0">
      <td><a href="#">+</a>Apples</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>On Store</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td>120</td>
      <td>120</td>
      <td>City 1</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td><a href="#">+</a>120</td>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>City 2</td>
      <td>22/10</td>
      <tr class="level2">
        <td>120</td>
        <td>140</td>
        <td>City 2</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="level2">
        <td>120</td>
        <td>140</td>
        <td>City 2</td>
        <td>22/10</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: @njeoo I've edited my answer according to your last comment. I don't use only "one" link. I usually search for the functionnality I'm looking for in Google, for example if you type "javascript add class", you'll find several different methods. By using these more and more, you'll learn which method to use in which case, and how to use those efficiently. But here is a link anyway, where you can find many, many, many things! https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: I have tried this just changed the css3 now able to see the tr :the following css i have                                                            
 `tbody > tr {
    display: table-row;
  }

  /* Simplified */
  tr.level0,
  tr.open {
    display: table-row;
  }
  `the js will be as below:while ((row = nextTr(row)) && (row.className.includes(cls) || row.className.includes("close")))
          row.classList.toggle("open"); 
      });

Comment: Takit Isy:please make changes in the snippets  that when we click the parent tr it should show the child tr with - minus symbol as a tr  when we click the child tr again it should close.

Comment: @njeoo I suggest you to try to use the new code, I've made a lot of modifications now. :)

Comment: Thank you so much....I will do that.Is it possible to pass the json data as parent and children tr.It should display only parent first when we click child it should display the child td.can you create json and pass data.

Comment: Which meants only one tr should get json and data from JavaScript property.basend on the click it should show only child.we should avoid hardcoding

Comment: Takit Isy: Could you please help on the question below:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747520/ndv3-chart-should-redraw-child-and-subchild-chart-by-clicking-on-it?noredirect=1#comment88503355_50747520

Comment: @njeoo are you the same person as piec00005?

Comment: @njeoo Why using multiple accounts?!

Comment: Takit Isy: can you please make it table as tree table below like this jsfiddle.jsfiddle.net/mehmetatas/fXzHS/2 –

Comment: @njeoo Can't do it easily, that's not a table.

Comment: The same Like  I wanted to have in table above table is it possible?

Comment: :can you make line in the above developed in each tr

Comment: Hi Takit Isy, Could you please check the issue? Price column should  splitted in in two columns wchich should expand the total value into sub value.                    
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907084/need-of-table-with-second-column-splitted-and-able-to-expand-the-price