# Angular recursive table issue

Tags: javascript, html

> I am implemented successfully the recursive table. Then I added the (click) method in the parent tr in order to call the child method to fetch data from database to display in the child tr.the problem is i am able to get the data in the child. but the child tr immediately appear and disappear.Could you please anyone help me on this to display the child tr when i click the  parent tr.

```js
sampletree() {
  var = ele < HTMLTableElement > document.getElementById("tableid");
  ele.addEventListener("click", (ev: MouseEvent) => {
    var element = ev.target as HTMLElement;
    if (element.tagName !== "A")
      return false;

    ev.preventDefault();
    var row = element.closest("tr");
    var cls = row.classList[0];
    var lvl = +(cls.slice(-1)) + 1;
    cls = cls.slice(0, -1) + lvl;

    while ((row = nextTr(row)) && (row.className.includes(cls) || row.className.includes("open")))
      row.classList.toggle("open");
  });

  function nextTr(row) {
    while ((row = row.nextSibling) && row.nodeType != 1);
    return row;
  }
}
getTableParent1(): void {
    this.service.getTableParent1()
      .subscribe(TableParent1 => this.TableParent1 = TableParent1;

      }
    getChild(): void {
        this.service.getTablechild1()
          .subscribe(Tablechild1 => this.Tablechild1 = Tablechild11;

          }
        ngOnInit() {
          this.TableParent1();
          this.sampletree();
        }
```

```css
tbody>tr {
  display: none;
}


/* Simplified */

tr.level0,
tr.open {
  display: table-row;
}


/* Added colors for better visibility */


/* Added some more styling after comment */

tr td {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

tr td:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

tr td a {
  color: #0e879a;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  position: relative;
  left: -0.73em;
  font-size: 19px;
}

tr.level1 td:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

tr.level2 td:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tableid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>test2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="level0" *ngFor="let tavles of tables">
      <td><a href="#" (click)="getChild()">+</a>{{tavles.test2}}</td>
      <td>{{tavles.test1}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1" *ngFor="let child of tablechild">
      <td><a href="#">+</a>{{child.test1}}</td>
      <td><a href="#">+</a>{{child.test2}} </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: For information, the previous question was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473899/need-of-recursive-html-table-tree-using-only-javascript

Comment: @Takit Isy I found something from the issue: i added the angular click function in the tr it self and again one more click function called from javascript.so when the frist click happends it shows the child and called the the addeventlistner  click function.are you able to get anything from my undestaning.

Comment: @Takit Isy:now i am able to see child tr but not able to  close it i have just changed css like this. 
tbody > tr {
    display: table-row;
  }

  /* Simplified */
  tr.level0,
  tr.open {
    display: table-row;
  }

Comment: `tbody>tr {
  display: none;
}` is used to hide the child rows, you're changing the features.

Comment: @Takit Isy: no problem is it possible to add minus symbol in  the child  tr to close instead of toggleing

Comment: can you make changes here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473899/need-of-recursive-html-table-tree-using-only-javascript/50474832?noredirect=1#comment88018227_50474832

Comment: the problem is with tr toggle