# How can I post-process my html to collapse large tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a placeholder on my webpage that is filled with a html table of matches/mismatches between files. The problem is that there's a lot of data that fills the page which may be a lot to scroll through and I'd like to make each table collapsible.

Perhaps post processing on the html table to collapse all rows under a header and just have a "+" button or something to show the rows if the user wants.

I'd like to avoid adding non-native css dependencies if possible.

```
<br>
<label style="font-weight:bold;color:#c9d3e0"> Header1 </label>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="Header Row">
          <td> (bunch of td cells for length of columns) </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="Matched Row">
          <td> (bunch of td cells for length of columns) </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="Mismatched Row">
          <td> (bunch of td cells for length of columns) </td>
      </tr>
   < /tbody>
</table>
<br>

(repeat for dynamic N tables)
```

Comment: can you use CSS visibility features? if so just add a class with javascript to the area you want to hide, and css will hide that class

Comment: Maybe this question where I answered a few days ago can be of some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473899/need-of-recursive-html-table-tree-using-only-javascript/50474832#50474832 Will you data be sorted like in your example, or will there some matched in the mismatched, and vice versa ?

Comment: I think the way this post is going is that I need my cs to dynamically add some literals when it is making the table. Can someone show me what just this table w/ proper html would look like if it was in the correct html formatting?

For example it would be:

Header1 + (that plus is a button)
(nothing underneath by default until that '+' is clicked)

Header 2 + 

etc. P.S. I do already have bootstrap dependencies ready to go. I see visibility collapsible as a possibility but I don't know how the above table should look since I'm new at formatting html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted and tried to enhance my answer from this other question ([Need of Recursive html table tree using only Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473899/need-of-recursive-html-table-tree-using-only-javascript)) to make it work with your example of data:

```js
function nextTr(row) {
  while ((row = row.nextSibling) && row.nodeType != 1);
  return row;
}

document.getElementById("myTable").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (!e) return;
  if (e.target.tagName !== "A") return;
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var row = e.target.closest("tr");
  var cls = row.classList[0];
  var lvl = +(cls.slice(-1)) + 1;
  cls = cls.slice(0, -1) + lvl;

  while ((row = nextTr(row)) && (row.className.includes(cls) || row.className.includes("open")))
    row.classList.toggle("open");
    
});

// Select all the tr childs elements (all levels except 0)
var allChilds = document.querySelectorAll("tr:not([class*=level0])");
document.getElementById("openAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  allChilds.forEach(function(elm){
    elm.classList.add("open");
  });
});
document.getElementById("closeAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  allChilds.forEach(function(elm){
    elm.classList.remove("open");
  });
});
```

```css
tbody tr {
  display: none;
}

th, td {
  padding: 4px 12px;
}

tr:first-of-type,
tr[class*="level0"],
tr.open {
  display: table-row;
}

tr[class*="level0"] th { background: #ccc; }
tr[class*="level1"] td { background: #ddd; }
tr[class*="level2"] td { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<button id="openAll">+ All</button>
<button id="closeAll">- All</button>
<br>
<label style="font-weight:bold;color:#c9d3e0"> Header1 </label>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="level0">
      <th><a>+/-</a></th><th>Header 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td></td><td>Match 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td></td><td>Match 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level0">
      <th><a>+/-</a></th><th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td></td><td>Match 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td><a>+/-</a></td><td>Match 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
      <td></td><td>Match 2.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level0">
      <th><a>+/-</a></th><th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td></td><td>Match 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level1">
      <td></td><td>Match 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Using this code, you can have several levels.

Feel free to comment if anything.
I hope it helps in any way.

Comment: Thanks, going to look at this for a while to understand how to implement it in my own code. If you have a second, could you help your explanation by showing what this would be if instead it was collapsible only for each header? E.g. only one +/- for each header. Header1 +/- (hidden by default tr's) then Header2 +/-, Header3 +/-, etc. since I'm generating this for some unknown length that would help me connect the dots.

Comment: @MarkMcGown I updated my answer. The `level0` elements are now `th` elements.