# Ndv3 chart should redraw child and subchild chart by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

> Hi Could you please help me to redraw the chart. 
>     http://jsfiddle.net/4auzLy21/1/
>    ................................................

when I click on the parent chart it has to show 
  the child with data?by clicking on the child chart 
  it has to show the sub child.For now I just have 
  the parent data.Please any one make changes on that.

...............................................................

```js
var data = [
    {"label":"Colorectale levermetastase (n=336)", "value":74}, 
    {"label":"Levensmetatase van andere origine (n=32)", "value":7}, 
    {"label":"Beningne levertumor (n=34)", "value":7},
    {"label": "Primaire maligne levertumor (n=56)", "value":12}
];


var colors = [
    'rgb(178, 55, 56)',
    'rgb(213, 69, 70)',
    'rgb(230, 125, 126)',
    'rgb(239, 183, 182)'
]


nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
        .color(colors)
        .showLabels(true)
        .labelType("percent")
//        .donut(true).donutRatio(0) /* Trick to make the labels go inside the chart*/
    ;
    
    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(chart)
    ;

    d3.selectAll(".nv-label text")
        /* Alter SVG attribute (not CSS attributes) */
        .attr("transform", function(d){
            d.innerRadius = -450;
            d.outerRadius = r;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";}
        )
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        /* Alter CSS attributes */
        .style({"font-size": "1em"})
    ;
    
    /* Replace bullets with blocks */
    d3.selectAll('.nv-series').each(function(d,i) {
        var group = d3.select(this),
            circle = group.select('circle');
        var color = circle.style('fill');
        circle.remove();
        var symbol = group.append('path')
            .attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type('square'))
            .style('stroke', color)
            .style('fill', color)
            // ADJUST SIZE AND POSITION
            .attr('transform', 'scale(1.5) translate(-2,0)')
    });

        
    return chart;
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Droid+Sans+Mono);

#chart svg {
  height: 600px;
}

.nv-label text{
    font-family: Droid Sans;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger! https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4auzLy21/1/

Comment: Show your research. A fiddle doesn't do this. debugging requires a human brain to make sense of each line of code, and most of the brains here are not interested in debugging your code. But! You _are_ interested in doing so. It's, like, your lucky day.

Comment: Read my comments carefully. I am saying you are expecting someone to debug your code for you. At least show what research you have done.